# Prevent database file from copying

Tags: sql-server, database, security

I want to deploy a .NET application on client machine. I don't know how to protect my database **.mdf** and **.ldf** files from copying. Is there any way to prevent them also from copying these files? I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: You ill deploy a DB in client server, server ill consume that DB but you want do deny they to copy your DB?

Comment: Yes I want to protect files from copying.

Comment: I'm sorry but what do you mean by Coping? You mean copying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer NO!

If they own that server there's little you can do.

If they are consuming your DB means they have a connection string to it. By using that connection string they can do a lot of things.

You can try to cryptography your DB, create just a handsome of users with specific crud operations permissions, etc.

But if they own the server they virtually have ultimate control over anything running on it.

And by the merit of just coping files, they can do what they want.

If you want to provide a service/application and don't want to provide clients to copy your precious data you ill need to host that by yourself or by a trustworthy third party.

Comment: I want protect my data base files from coping.

Comment: @AbdullahQudeer: you can't protect the files - simple as that (If they can't be copied, how would you copy them *to* the system in the first place?)

Comment: I just create database in sqlserver 2008-R2.this will make two files in **.mdf** and **.ldf**. I want to protect these two files

Comment: Let's put it simple. You brought a nice car sound system. If you install it on your car you can lock down it and protect your car. If you install it on client car he can just drive off with it.